# Erro ao chamar variável fora da função

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    var rtn = null;
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    }).then(function(response) {
        var files = response.result.files;
        rtn = files[0]["id"];
    });
    console.log(rtn);
```

A variável `files`não está vazia, já tentei de diversas formas passar o seu valor, ou usar um `return`, porém `rtn` continua como `null`, eu também tentei:

```
    var rtn = {};
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = '"+name+"' and '1zo-0IG0d7v91P25Ln6haxF2isMbt0hN8' in parents",
    }).then(function(response) {
        var files = response.result.files;
        rtn.file = files[0]["id"];
    });
```

E ao dar um `console.log(rtn)` fora da função, existe `rtn.file` com o suposto valor, porém quando chamo diretamente o mesmo com `rtn.file`, diz que é `undefined`, o que está acontecendo e como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: da um `console.log(response)` dentro da função pra ver

Answer (score 0):

Como a função é assíncrona, o console.log(rtn) está sendo executado antes de receber o valor.
Sugiro a seguinte alteração:

```
    var rtn = null;
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    }).then(function(response) {
        var files = response.result.files;
        rtn = files[0]["id"];
        console.log(rtn);
    });
```

Comment: como ele declarou a variável fora da função o `console.log(rtn)` que estava fora deveria funcionar

Comment: Como ele informou, ela funciona, mas retorna null, que foi o valor atribuído antes da função.

Comment: Preciso chamar esses dados fora função, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Deve haver opção melhor, mas uma possibilidade seria usar setTimeout(function(){ console.log(rtn); }, 1000);